# Modifying wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In the mobile view, I currently have have a hamburger bars menu which, when pressed, drops to 'home' + site search. If it's pressed again it drops to a full menu. In the desktop view I have the word 'home' which, when pressed drops to 'home' which, when pressed again drops to full menu.

I just want bars (hamburger) that drop to full menu, when pressed in desktop view.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div class="module-group right">
<div class="module left">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1- 
collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu- 
 item-1496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type 
 menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu- 
 item page_item page-item-19 current_page_item menu- 
 item-has-children menu-item-1496 dropdown active"><a 
 title="Home" href="https://adsler.co.uk/">Home </a> vv. 
 <span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data- 
 toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria- 
 hidden="true"></i></span>
 <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">.                      
 <li id="menu-item-1499"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want hamburger menu in desktop view too???? If I am correct you may try overlay menu.May refer codepen overlay menu.

Comment: Thanks. How do I do overlay menu?

Comment: And what is it?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. Where would i insert html? Header php? Also, presumably id delete current html or would new simply override it?

Comment: Yeah...Add this in header.php file..It only override your file..If this answer helps you please mark it as right.

Comment: Camae out like this. https://www.adsler.co.uk and didn't over write code. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copied the css there??